# Django view give ''int' object has no attribute'' when in shell gives object from model

Tags: python, django

I got this error when I'm trying to obtain data from models in my view.Thing is, I understand clearly what this error is,but I am very confused why it is happening.It is becouse when I run following code in django shell i'm getting what i want.

In django shell:

```
In [2]: from ep.models import *

In [3]: a = PreventionProgramCenter.objects.all()

In [4]: a.values_list('center',flat=True)
Out[4]: <QuerySet [1, 2, 3]>

In [5]: b=a[0]

In [6]: b
Out[6]: <PreventionProgramCenter: PreventionProgramCenter object (1)>

In [7]: b.center.zip_code
Out[7]: '53-334'

In [8]: for i in a:
   ...:         print(i)
   ...:     
PreventionProgramCenter object (1)
PreventionProgramCenter object (2)
PreventionProgramCenter object (3)
```

It is all good.I can get list of object from my model,iterate over it and calls methods.

But in my view.py

```
    zip_codes = []
    zip_codes_obj = PreventionProgramCenter.objects.all()
    zip_codes_obj = zip_codes_obj.values_list('center',flat=True)
    for zip_code in zip_codes_obj:
        print(zip_code)
        zip_codes.append(zip_code.center.zip_code)
```

`zip_code` is just int,not object of PreventionProgramCenter.How,what I'm missing?

Comment: Note that your `a.values_list('center',flat=True)` call does *not* change the state, you constructed a *new* `QuerySet`, you did not change the *old* one.

Comment: But note also that you *don't need* (or Indeed want) to use values_list here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell example you are not assigning the `value_list` to `a` otherwise you'd get the same error as in your view.

```
In [3]: a = PreventionProgramCenter.objects.all()

In [4]: a.values_list('center',flat=True)
Out[4]: <QuerySet [1, 2, 3]>
```

Here, variable `a` stays `PreventionProgramCenter.objects.all()`, iterable of `PreventionProgramCenter` objects. While in the view code

```
zip_codes_obj = PreventionProgramCenter.objects.all()
zip_codes_obj = zip_codes_obj.values_list('center',flat=True)
```

You are assigning to `zip_codes_obj` a `values_list` ~ list of integers.

Comment: How i could miss that.Thank you!